# Having trouble with my Haskell code

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghci

I'm trying to write some code in Haskell using ghci 7.8.3. 
When I type this code `[x*2 ¦ x <- [1..10]]` it gives me an error saying that it does not understand what `<-` is. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because it should be like this:

```
[x*2 | x <- [1..10]] -- notice | instead of ¦
```

Sample demo in ghci:

```
λ> [x*2 ¦ x <- [1..10]]
<interactive>:2:10: parse error on input `<-'
λ> [x*2 | x <- [1..10]]
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
```

Comment: @Nicholas Make sure that you have the proper keyboard layout set (preferably US or UK).